# How to search for required data in JSON object obtained in python session

Tags: python, json, twitter, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I tried to scrape twitter followers using requests library. finally, i tried to save the response of required page in json format and then tried to search for the required parts. The thing is, how to find required elements in the json object?
my code is:

```
    s =requests.session()
res = s.post("https://twitter.com/sessions",data=payload,headers=headers)
r = s.get("https://twitter.com/akhiltaker619/following/users?include_available_features=1&include_entities=1&max_position=1590310744326457266&reset_error_state=false")

dp = r.text

dp1=json.loads(dp)

x = json.dumps(dp1)
print(res.status_code)

soup = BeautifulSoup(x,"html.parser")
x1= soup.find_all("b",{"class":"u-linkComplex-target"})
for i in x1:
    print(i.text)
```

At the end parsing part is wrong as i am trying to scrape json object which is not possible. When i print the json object, i get this:

[The link is attached which contains the output of json object](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_BEicHuC3cpQhtrH440TvwwMESP_jyM2)
now from this object, i want "class : u-linkComplex-target" present in the "item_html" of this json object. How to get this? Or is there any way to get the same content without using json object(this content is the followers list page in twitter). I used json inorder to load the dynamic content of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Beautiful Soup library is for parsing HTML and similar tagged languages, not JSON.

If your requests return JSON responses then you should call the `r.json()` method. This will return a dictionary of the JSON structure. Suppose you used

```
j = r.json()
```

then you probably want `j['item-html']['linkComplex-target']` or something similar. If you access the dictionary interactively you will probably find what you want.